# Apache configuration settings for specific port (PCI Compliance)

Tags: apache, security, httpd.conf, pci-compliance

I am trying to make my server PCI Compliant. One of the last issues that I need to fix is to remove the INode from Apache ETag header. So I defined in httpd.conf this line: "FileETag MTime Size" to only return **MTime** and **Size**.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    FileETag MTime Size
</Directory>
```

This fix solved issue for standard port 80.

Now, I also have hosting control panel (ISPConfig3) running on port 8000. After running PCI compliance test I got this error:

> Apache ETag header discloses inode numbers Severity: Potential Problem
>   CVE: CVE-2003-1418 Impact: A remote attacker could determine inode
>   numbers on the server. Resolution Use the
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#FileETag FileETag
>   directive to remove the INode component from the calculation of the
>   ETag. For example, place the following line in the Apache
>   configuration file to calculate the ETag based only on the file's
>   modification time and size: FileETag MTime Size Vulnerability Details:
>   Service: 8000:TCP

I assume I have to add something in httpd.conf to also apply **FileETag** to all applications running on port 8000.

Please advice what should be done.

Thank you!
Kelvin

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your PCI Compliance test is out of date.  Have you read [CVE-2003-1418](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2003-1418)?

> Apache HTTP Server *1.3.22 through 1.3.27* on OpenBSD allows remote attackers to obtain sensitive information via (1) the ETag header, which reveals the inode number, or (2) multipart MIME boundary, which reveals child proccess IDs (PID).

[My *Ital*] This isn't an issue for Apache 2.2 which uses a different Etag algo.  And if you are still running Apache 1.3  then you've got bigger problems since it is no longer supported.

You are trying to solve a non-problem.  Get yourself a current PCI Compliance test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the beginning of your /etc/apache2/http.conf:

```
#PCI Compliance fix for "Apache ETag header discloses inode numbers"
Header unset ETag
FileETag MTime Size
```

This worked for my PCI compliance scan and I don't see why it wouldn't work on all ports that apache listens on.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apache 2.4 FileETag directive documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#fileetag) the default used for calculating the ETag is `MTime Size`.

For Apache versions 2.3.14 and earlier the default was set to `INode MTime Size`.

**ETag settings for all ports and checking Apache ETag output**

You can check for yourself by using curl and comparing the ETag value returned in the headers versus the inode value returned by `ls`.

For example:

```
 curl -I https://example.com/file
```

where *file* is a file that is on your filesystem served by your Apache web server.

With ETag set to `MTime Size` you might see something like this:

```
ETag: "3-24f10051b181e"
```

You can change the values returned by ETag by using the `FileETag` directive. Add to the bottom of your Apache server conf (e.g. `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) file the following:

```
FileETag INode
```

Reload or restart Apache and then repeat the curl test.

In my tests, ***inclusion of FileETag INode in the server config file affected output on ALL ports being served by my Apache web server: 80 and 443.***

With ETag set to `INode` you should receive a single hex number, something like this:

```
ETag: "200f8fa"
```

Convert the numbers returned by ETag from hex to decimal and compare to the inode number.

If you run `ls -i /path/to/webroot/example.com/file` the inode returned should be the decimal equivalent of the hex number returned via ETag (in this example 33618170).

If you added `FileETag Inode` don't forget to remove it and restart/reload Apache.

**ETag settings for a specific port**

The contexts where you can use `FileETag` are:

- server config
- virtual host
- directory
- .htaccess

If `FileETag` is present in the server config with the component keywords you desire and you are still seeing incorrect ETag output for a specific port that Apache is serving, you should search vhost config files and web root directories for `FileETag` - as any settings there will override the server config.

If you actually want to have a specific ETag output on a specific port, you should add `FileETag` to the appropriate `VirtualHost` block for the port you want to affect. If you are serving more than one site on this port, you'll need to add `FileETag` to each `VirtualHost` block that specifies that port.